# how to keep data when user key personal in program and keep it in new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to write a python program to ask the users (3 users) to type their information such as Name,
Age, Email and create a file as name “personal_info.txt” containing all the information
entered?

Example Input

```
Enter name: A
Enter age: 1
Enter email: 
keep data 3 times and keep in data
```

in file

a 10 hero1@hotmail.com

b 11 hero2@hotmail.com

c 12 hero3@hotmail.com

I'm trying to do this but I don't know what next

```
personal_file = open("data/personal_info.txt", "w")
for i in range(1, 4):
name = input("Enter your name : ")
age = int(input("Enter your Age : "))
email = input("Enter your Email : ")
code to keep data...
```

thankyou

Comment: Start with a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) then see [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you don't know how to save data
from input into the file.The code to achieve what you want can be something like
this:

```
names, ages, emails = [], [], []
for _ in range(3):
    names.append(input("Enter your name : "))
    ages.append(int(input("Enter your Age : ")))
    emails.append(input("Enter your Email : "))
with open("data/personal_info.txt", "w") as f:
    for name, age, email in zip(names, ages, emails):
        f.write(name + age + email + '\n\n')
```

It's strongly recommended to use context managers when working with files.
You should also add try except blocks, because working with users input is very error prone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use write or writelines to write user inputs to your text file:

```
personal_file = open("personal_info.txt", "w")
for i in range(3):
    name = input("Enter your name : ")
    age = int(input("Enter your Age : "))
    email = input("Enter your Email : ")
    personal_file.writelines(f'{name}\n{age}\n{email}\n\n\n')
personal_file.close()
```